# phpmyadmin|How to create an event do 2 actions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create an event that can do two actions but I don't know how.
Here is the query:

```
CREATE EVENT rate ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2011-12-01 20:00:00' DO SET @p=1
UPDATE users SET rate = (@p:=@p+1) ORDER BY power DESC
```

I tried also to write AND between the actions and it still writes an error.

The error is:

```
\#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE users SET rate = (@p:=@p+1) ORDER BY power DESC' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the body of your event in a [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) compound statement block:

```
CREATE EVENT rate ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2011-12-01 20:00:00' DO BEGIN
  SET @p=1;
  UPDATE users SET rate = (@p:=@p+1) ORDER BY power DESC;
END
```

Note that each statement must be terminated with a semicolon, so you must configure your client to use a different statement delimiter in order that it does not think the first encountered semicolon is the end of the `CREATE EVENT` command (how to do this will depend on your client, but in the [MySQL command line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html), you can use the `DELIMITER` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html) and in phpMyAdmin you can set the delimiter below the SQL input box).

Alternatively, in this case you can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to perform variable initialisation such that you only require a single simple statement:

```
CREATE EVENT rate ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2011-12-01 20:00:00' DO
  UPDATE   users, (SELECT @p:=0) init
  SET      users.rate = (@p:=@p+1)
  ORDER BY users.power DESC
```

Comment: @רותםשמחי: For the first query, did you set the statement delimiter as explained in the body of my answer?  For the second query, could you explain what you mean by "*it doesn't work*"?

Comment: i didnt understand how to use delimeter

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the semicolons `;` after your statements.

Try this:

```
CREATE EVENT rate ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2011-12-01 20:00:00' 
      DO SET @p=1;
UPDATE users SET rate = (@p:=@p+1) ORDER BY power DESC;
```

Comment: But now the phpmyadmin see only the first action.

Comment: @רותםשמחי They are two separate queries. Try putting them in one procedure if that would work for you.

Comment: how can i do that? i dont know how to make it one query

Comment: Look up how to make a mysql procedure on the interwebs. B'Hatzlacha!

Comment: i dont know english well. can you help me to find out how to do that? pls :(

Comment: Sorry... Just look up on google "mysql prcedure" and you will get results :-)