# What is wrong with my syntax when creating an event? phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been at this for hours now, and I have tried everything I could find on stackoverflow and the internet. Nothing has worked. I have tried entering the code directly in the SQL prompt on phpmyadmin, as well as tried to create the event in the events tab.

For some odd reason, when giving it a second command, I get a syntax error. Each command on its own is accepted just fine. Together though? Syntax error.

Here's the code.

```
CREATE EVENT update_stats
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 

BEGIN 
UPDATE stats JOIN temp_stats ON stats.unique_key = temp_stats.unique_key
SET stats.clicks = stats.clicks + temp_stats.clicks;

TRUNCATE temp_stats;
END
```

This yields a syntax error. I found a similar question on stackoverflow (see below) but none of the solutions worked.  Yes, I tried setting and using a different delimiter. I even updated phpmyadmin to 4.4.1. Nothing works, just says I have a syntax error. I'm at my wits end here. MySQL 5.6.17.

[phpmyadmin|How to create an event do 2 actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994159/phpmyadminhow-to-create-an-event-do-2-actions?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer is missing an explanation as Jean-Francois was the correct answer but I didn't get it to work until I worked out what the "Delimiter" is.

When sending commands to SQL they are separated with a "Delimiter" the default is ";"

When I was making my event, inside the "CREATE EVENT" statement contains SQL queries inside the "BEGIN" and "END". SO MYSQL, parsing the query, runs into a ';' inside the BEGIN statement and correctly ends the statement there, saying "error in syntax near '' at line X" (the line it found the semi-colon on).

So to get around this you have to change the default delimiter for parsing, then run the query so you can include SQL statements inside your CREATE EVENT query with it ignoring the semi-colon and set the default delimiter back to a semi-colon:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `snap_extcrs`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2020-04-17 23:59:59'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table (field, field2)
SELECT 1, 2 FROM table2
WHERE 
    date = DATE(NOW());

INSERT INTO table3 (field, field2)
SELECT 1, 2 FROM table2
WHERE 
    date = DATE(NOW());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the `END` delimiter

```
DELIMITER @
CREATE EVENT update_stats
   ON SCHEDULE 
       EVERY 15 MINUTE
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
   DO BEGIN
           UPDATE stats JOIN temp_stats ON stats.unique_key = temp_stats.unique_key
           SET stats.clicks = stats.clicks + temp_stats.clicks;

           TRUNCATE temp_stats;
   END@
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Copied your exact code... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '| 
DELIMITER' at line 12

Comment: @MikelG Updated, I was able to run this one without any errors.

Comment: Still doesn't work BUT putting it directly into the MySQL command line DOES work.  What's more, creating the Event on the 'events' tab using everything between `BEGIN...END` works as well. I tried that before and it didn't work, but that was before I updated to 4.4.1.

Comment: @MikelG If it works in raw MySQL, on my MySQL editor, but doesn't on yours then sorry I can't help. I fixed the end incorrect delimiter but this was the only thing stopping your query from compiling when C&P in my editor. What editor do you use ?

Comment: I was putting it into the SQL prompt in phpMyAdmin. It doesn't work there. However, in mysql console, it works fine. Also, it works fine in the "events" tab in phpMyAdmin. I'll just resort to the console from now on for stuff like this. Thanks.

Comment: @MikelG You're welcome. Just so you know, I use MySQL workbench.