# Error in create event query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing this query:

```
CREATE EVENT `event_maid_availability` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS 
'2015-08-12 10:16:47' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
SET @t1:=1;
INSERT INTO `maid_slots_availabilty`(`maid_slot_id`, `date`, `status`)
SELECT maids_slots.id,
              DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL @t := @t + 1 DAY),
              maids_slots.status
FROM
  (SELECT *
    FROM maids_slots
    WHERE status = '1'
      AND end_date IS NULL) AS `maids_slots`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT day_slot_id
    FROM day_slots
    WHERE day_id = DAYOFWEEK( curdate())-1) AS day_slots
WHERE day_slots.day_slot_id = maids_slots.day_slot_id;
  ALTER TABLE maid_slots_availabilty AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; END;
```

And I am getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I am spend two days on this but I am not able to find where is the problem.

Comment: use delimiter something as `delimiter //` at the start and at the end `end;//`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked removing the ` marks and then trying again? Sometimes for some reason it's my problem!!

for example because of ` mark usage for table name I was getting an error message

Comment: " ` " can solve problems in MySQL, and not to add them usually.

Comment: I have tried both with " ` " and without " ` " but same error persist

Comment: "`" backticks are used to escape column and table names when you use mysql reserved words for name or when the table/column name contains whitespaces. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) for further details. This is not OP situation.

Answer (score 0):

Then you are running create event or procedure statements via the MySQL console, you should change the delimiter first. Otherwise - it thinks that you running a list of commands and then you get this error.

So to avoid this problem you should set a different delimiter.
so basically your code should look like this:

```
delimiter ||

CREATE EVENT `event_maid_availability` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND 
STARTS 
'2015-08-12 10:16:47' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
SET @t1:=1;
INSERT INTO `maid_slots_availabilty`(`maid_slot_id`, `date`, `status`)
SELECT maids_slots.id,
              DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @t := @t + 1 DAY),
              maids_slots.status
FROM
  (SELECT *
    FROM maids_slots
    WHERE status = '1'
      AND end_date IS NULL) AS `maids_slots`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT day_slot_id
    FROM day_slots
    WHERE day_id = DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1) AS day_slots
WHERE day_slots.day_slot_id = maids_slots.day_slot_id;
  ALTER TABLE maid_slots_availabilty AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; 
END; ||

delimiter ;
```

Here I set the delimiter to `||` but you can use any other character that is not previously used in your code.

> UPDATE:

You have another option when you work from console directly.

You can run `edit` command which will open you the default editor.
Write your event there. 
Save the document
Then prompt will return to `->` sign of MySQL - add `;` (which is the default delimiter)

Here is a reference to a MySQL commands page
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html

> UPDATE 2:

If you are using phpAdmin - check out this video. [phpMyAdmin tutorial at Debconf13, part 4 : triggers/routines/events and server status monitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZRZoCsrKis)

Comment: i got   this  -#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1

Comment: what is the version of MySQL you are using? (and check the other option I have added in the update

Comment: 5.6.24 is the version I am using

Comment: write the exact command that you are typing. here is exactly how it works `mysql> delimiter ||
mysql>`

Comment: I have pasted the query you suggested in the phpmyadmin query box and press 'go' and then it showed me the error

Comment: this works in the normal mysql command line. phpadmin - can do a lot of stuff that I'm not aware of. you should write that you are using phpadmin next time.  You can open a console and it will work with no problem.

Comment: found more people complaining about the same here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994159/phpmyadminhow-to-create-an-event-do-2-actions) for example. and no solution. I personally do not use phpadmin, so can not test it .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have already read MySQL documentation and using similar query as they are using in their example in the docs and still i am getting error.

Comment: MySQL documentation is not relevant for phpAdmin for 100%. You should use the console :) and will have no problems